# Add filename increment in my script

Tags: powershell

I have created a script that will rename pst files to acl owner. It works. The only problem i have is when there are two pst files in the same folder.It gives them the same name. How can i add an increment in my script. It ried it with Si = 1 and Si++ but with no results.

Here is my script:

```cs
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\tester\* -Filter *.pst -recurse |
    ForEach-Object{
        $owner = ( $_ | Get-Acl ).Owner.Split("\")[1]
        $newname = "$owner.pst"
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newname -Verbose -WhatIf
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick and fast work around by adding names already used to an array and checking each time you loop.

```cs
$increment = 1
$alreadyProcessed = @()    
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\tester\* -Filter *.pst -recurse |
        ForEach-Object{
            $owner = ( $_ | Get-Acl ).Owner.Split("\")[1]
            $newname = "$owner.pst"
            if($alreadyProcessed.Contains($newName))
            {
                $newName = "$owner`$increment.pst"
                $increment++
            }
            $alreadyProcessed += $newname

            $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newname -Verbose -WhatIf
        }
```

This will ensure a unique name each time.

Comment: Why are you escaping the `$` in `$newName`?

Comment: It may not be needed. I think I wanted to make sure each variable was listed, even the one right after the second.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to run your script multiple times in the same place then you should check to see what names are available otherwise your counter will reset to 1 but those files would already exist.

```
function Get-NextName ($file) {

    $existing = (Get-Item "$file.*").Name
    $i = 1

    while ($existing -contains "$file.$i") {
        $i++
    }

    "$file.$i"
}
```

And then adjust your function:

```cs
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\tester\* -Filter *.pst -recurse |
    ForEach-Object{
        $owner = ( $_ | Get-Acl ).Owner.Split("\")[1]
        $newname = Get-NextName "$owner.pst"
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newname -Verbose -WhatIf
    }
```